# Python - list of lists, add second values where firsts are equals

Tags: python, list

I have lists in a list like :

```
liste = [[36, 6], [1, 2], [5, 3], [10, 8], [36, 8]]
```

The goal is to add the 2nd values where the first values are identical; such as :

```
liste = [[36, 14], [1, 2], [5, 3], [10, 8]]
```

- *[36, 6] and [36, 8] => [36, 6+8]*

Comment: show us what you've already written / tried, and we will be able to assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group them using a dictionary:

```py
values = [[36, 6], [1, 2], [5, 3], [10, 8], [36, 8]]

def solve(values):
    # Create a dictionary to store as key the first element
    # of each sublist mapped to a list of second elements
    result = {}

    for k, v in values:
        # Append the second element from the sublists to an 
        # empty list if the first element does not yet exists
        # in the dictionary else to the already existing list
        result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

    # Return the sum of each list
    return [[k, sum(v)] for k, v in result.items()]
        
print(solve(values))
# Outputs [[36, 14], [1, 2], [5, 3], [10, 8]]
```